# What  is wrong in this c# 3.0 code?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have this code below.

```
 delegate void TestDel(string str);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestDel td = name=> Console.WriteLine(name);
            TestDel td = (string name) { Console.WriteLine(name);}
            td("hello");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Here I have a delegate TestDel , which is created first by using a lambda expression which goes fine.
But the second method where I am using an anonymous method it doesn't compile but if do like below:

```
TestDel td = delegate(string name) { Console.WriteLine(name);};
```

Then everything is fine, my confusion is that why can I use lambda expression and not anonymous method while they are same , why do i need to put delegate with anonymous method but not with lambda expression ?

Comment: because that's how you write anonymous methods in C#: you use the `delegate` keyword; without the `delegate` keyword you don't have an anonymous method, you have a block of code with an invalid statement sitting before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example should be:

```
TestDel td = (string name) => { Console.WriteLine(name); };
```

Comment: @Praveen - Then I don't really understand your question - what you have now isn't syntactically valid.

Comment: I think the question is more "why isn't it syntactically valid" -- which is probably not really a question that can get a good answer here, other than it just isn't, it says so in the spec.

Comment: Yes you are right , i saw the syntax now, that was my mistake but I am still surprised why can't compiler figure out that this can be used as the body to execute and convert it to delegate underneath...

Answer (score 2):

Because anonymous methods *are created* using the `delegate` keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx That's how the language works.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions and anonymous methods are separate language features. A lambda looks like this:

```
a => Something(a)
```

And an anonymous method looks like this:

```
delegate (string a) { Something(a); }
```

Think of it as the difference between an anonymous type and a class, where the lambda is the anonymous method, and the delegate is the class.